# NodeJS run server for receiving POST and serve GET

Tags: node.js, post, get, httprequest

1) Running a NodeJS server on localmachine

2) One device with App making a POST req to Node server.

3) XAMPP page making a GET request to get what device (from point 2) sent to Node server.

hope that's clear.

this is what I have, but GET receives undefined. 
POST logs `key1=value1`

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

console.log(req.method);

var txt;

if(req.method == "POST") {

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');

    var url = require("url"),
        parsedUrl = url.parse(req.url, false), // true to get query as object
        queryAsObject = parsedUrl.query;

    txt = JSON.stringify(queryAsObject);

    console.log(txt);

} else {

    // for GET requests, serve up the contents in 'index.html'
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end('Hello Worldzz\n'); // I WANT TO PASS txt here. 

    console.log("jaa" + txt);
}


}).listen(1337, 'my.ip.here');
console.log('Server running at http://my.ip.here:1337/');
```

-- update. CHECKing

```
function checkServer() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://my.ip.here:1337/",
        async: false,
    }).success(function( text ) {
        console.log("res" + text);
        $( "h2" ).text( text );
    });
}
```

Comment: The server works properly, 'txt' is not defined in the code, so what is the problem?

Comment: I have an index.html with script.js jquery Ajax GET

Comment: Then, what did you expected to get, GET request would receive 'Hello Worldzz\n'

Comment: txt is defined. like I wrote, I would like to GET the `txt` what I get from the POST.

Comment: @bboy that's not possible. the POST portion only gets entered on POST. on GET requests `txt` remains undefined. Though, you could of course define `txt` one scope higher so that it is shared for all requests.

Comment: can't i save to memory and read from there?

Comment: try res.end(txt); instead of res.end('Hello Worldzz\n')

Comment: tried, but getting `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a simple scope problem. Since you want all requests to share the same `txt` var, you'll need to define `txt` in a place where all requests can access it.

```
var http = require('http');
var txt;
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    console.log(req.method);

    //var txt;
```